# Post to PHP script after successful paypal payment

Tags: php, html, email, post, paypal

I have an html form for registering for a club. I then have a php script that I want to have called that will send an email to me with the registration info. What I need to have happen is have the PHP script called once I get a successful payment through paypal. Under sandbox I am successfully hitting the 'onApprove' callback. I just wonder how I call the PHP file and post the data from the form. Any help would be appreciated. Or if there's a better way to do it, please let me know.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Add padding to containers */
.container {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Overwrite default styles of hr */
hr {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/* Set a style for the submit button */
.registerbtn {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.registerbtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Add a blue text color to links */
a {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

/* Set a grey background color and center the text of the "sign in" section */
.signin {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" name="emailregistration" action="form-to-email.php">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to register.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="email"><b>Email*</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="user@email.com" name="email" id="email" required>

    <label for="name"><b>Name (First Last)*</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="John Smith" name="name" id="name" required>

    <label for="address"><b>Address*</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="555 S Main, Prosper, TX 75078" name="address" id="address" required>

    <label for="phone"><b>Phone Number*</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="555-555-5555" name="phone" id="phone" required>

    <label for="age"><b>Age*</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="35" name="age" id="age" required>

    <br>
    <br>

    <label><b>Experience Level-I played in...*</b></label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="experience" id="neverPlayed" value="never" required>
    <label for="neverPlayed">I've never played organized football</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="experience" id="middleSchool" value="middleSchool" required>
    <label for="middleSchool">Middle School</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="experience" id="highSchool" value="highSchool" required>
    <label for="highSchool">High School</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="experience" id="College" value="college" required>
    <label for="college">College</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="experience" id="semiPro" value="semiPro" required>
    <label for="semiPro">Semi-Pro</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="experience" id="professional" value="professional" required>
    <label for="professional">Professional</label><br>

    <br>
    <br>

    <label><b>Team Designation*</b></label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="team" id="captain" value="captain" required>
    <label for="captain">I wish to Captain a team (you will receive an additional email requesting more information)</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="team" id="placed" value="placed" required>
    <label for="placed">I wish to be placed on a currently formed team (team name and captain's name required next)</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="team" id="added" value="added" required>
    <label for="added">I wish to be added to a new team</label><br>

    <br>
    <br>

    <label for="formedteam"><b>If you answered "I wish to be placed on a currently formed team" above, please provide the team name and captain's name.</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your answer" name="formedteam" id="formedteam">

    <label for="request"><b>Special Request (i.e. To be placed on the same team as another player)</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your answer" name="request" id="request">

    <label for="emergency"><b>Emergency Contact Name/Phone Number/Relationship</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your answer" name="emergency" id="emergency">

    <label for="emergency2"><b>2nd Emergency Contact Name/Phone Number/Relationship</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your answer" name="emergency2" id="emergency2">

    <hr>
   

    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
    <div>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=[key]">
    </script>
  
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
  
    <script>
        paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: '69.99'
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                  $.post("form-to-email.php", {
                      value: document.forms[emailregistration]
                  }, function(data) {
                    window.location.href = 'index';
                    alert("Success");
                  });

                    // document.forms["emailregistration"].submit(function() {
                    //   alert("Success");
                    // });
                    
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

if(empty($name))
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
}

$email_from = "email@email.com";
$email_subject = "New Registration";
$email_body = "There is a new registration from $name.\n email- $email";
$to = "email@email.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/

Comment: @AbraCadaver I am not looking at how to know if the payment was made, I just need to know how to call the php script once the payment has been made.

Comment: That's what it does.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I am not seeing where it tells me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make a call to the PHP file after a successful payment, you could easily do a call to the file using jQuery's `.post()` method.

Below is an example of how the post call would look in your JavaScript code. Using this will successfully call your PHP file once the JavaScript is invoked and you can use the `data` payload to return the data from the PHP file back to the original page.

```
  $.post("yourfile.php",
  {
    value1: "Red",
    value2: "Blue"
  },
  function(data){
    alert("Data: " + data);
  });
```

For a better understanding of the `jQuery.post()` method, you can view the documentation here:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Thank you. I got that working now, but now it just navigates to a blank page, and shows that it's on the php script. How do I prevent that? (i.e. www.mypage.com/script.php)

Comment: @linuxer Are you saying the browser redirects to the PHP file once the function is called? Are there any errors that appear in the browser console that could be related to the issue?

Comment: yes, that's what I am saying. It redirects. If I add echo"$name" then is shows the value for that. I don't get any errors.

Comment: The same thing happens if I call document.forms["emailregistration"].submit()

Comment: Hmm, not sure what would be causing that. Are you able to post the full HTML of the page? I'd like to see what's going on with that, but I don't believe the snippets are enough to run through the functions.

Comment: I'll post it. I did realize, though, that it actually only happens when either hitting the submit button, and not going through paypal, or calling the document.forms.submit. If I do the $.post it doesn't redirect.

Comment: Posted the full html

Comment: So in your post you show value1: "Red", etc.  How would I send all the values from the form?

Comment: It should be as simple as using ````$("form").serialize()````

More details: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Tried out the code myself and it works flawlessly, so not quite sure why you're experiencing a problem with it. Make sure you're including jQuery on the page?

Comment: I didn't have it included. I added <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script> just after the <head> is that correct? It still doesn't work for me. Running it with the document.form.submit() does send the email. So I know it's not the script. I am guessing that I need to add jquery somewhere else, and that right now the script isn't being called.

Comment: Placing it after the <head> should be fine, just as long as it's included before the start of the JavaScript. Are you running through the PayPal checkout flow? That's what I had done and after I placed a sandbox order, a post request was sent to the page and I could retrieve the data.

Comment: Yeah, I am running through paypal. I just now got an email from the script, but it doesn't have any data from the form. So I guess I am still passing that incorrectly. At least now I know the script is called.  $.post("form-to-email.php", $("#emailregistration").serialize(), function(data) {
                     alert("Success");
                  });

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. I was missing the id tag in the form. Once I set that I am now getting the data. Thanks! I truly appreciate the fast responses.